# Class instance generation resulting in undefined variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having issues implementing my random stat generation module with my class generation module. The individual functions in the stat generation module work fine when tested individually but "variable not defined" errors pop up consistently when I try to implement them with the class.

I swear the issue is something stupid that I'm completely missing, but I've changed so many things to no avail I've got nowhere left to turn to.

I've tried changing the variables in the class initiation and the dunder main class initiation. I've also tried directly returning values and it still says variable not defined.

Currently calling upon it as it stands results in:

```
  Car_1 = Car(speed(), acceleration(), handling(), braking(), durability())
NameError: name 'speed' is not defined
```

**`statgen.py`**:

```
import random


def speed():
    speed_base = random.randint(50, 100)
    speed_tmp = float(speed_base/10)
    if speed_tmp == 10:
        return 10
    else:
        return int(speed_tmp)

def acceleration():
    acc_base = random.randint(59, 100)
    acc_tmp = float(acc_base/10)
    if acc_tmp == 10:
        return 10
    else:
        return int(acc_tmp)

def handling():
    hnd_base = random.randint(30, 100)
    hnd_tmp = float(hnd_base/10)
    if hnd_tmp == 10:
        return 10
    else:
        return int(hnd_tmp)

def braking():
    brake_base = random.randint(55, 100)
    brake_tmp = float(brake_base/10)
    if brake_tmp == 10:
        return 10
    else:
        return int(brake_tmp)

def durability():
    dur_base = random.randint(35, 100)
    dur_tmp = float(dur_base/10)
    if dur_tmp == 10:
        return 10
    else:
        return int(dur_tmp)
```

**`car.py`**:

```
import statgen


class Car:
    def __init__(self, speed, acceleration, handling, braking, durability):
        self.speed = speed
        self.acceleration = acceleration
        self.handling = handling
        self.braking = braking
        self.durability = durability


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Car_1 = Car(speed(), acceleration(), handling(), braking(), durability())
```

`Car_1` generation should produce stats relating to each variable within the confinements of each variables potential value.
For example, `Car_1` should return something like `[7, 8, 5, 6, 8]` for its stat values.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Those variables are the functions he defined.

Comment: `Car_1 = Car(speed(), acceleration(), handling(), braking(), durability())`

Comment: I tried previously using return within the stat generation files, but that still resulted with the same variable not defined issue. I could try outright assigning variables to call upon the functions, but I want it to randomly generate for each class generation.

Comment: All your functions are exactly the same, except for the first argument to `randint()`. Why don't you define a single function that takes that value as a parameter?

Comment: Is this all in one file??

Comment: Currently two files. The import random and variable generations are all in a "statgen.py" file that is imported at the start of the class generation file.

Comment: Please show us the code in your class generation file that imports variables from `statgen.py`.

Comment: Can I see? :) Just post the whole of both files and the full traceback please. We need to test.

Comment: Yep there's the problem! See answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import code from a different file, it has a different namespace. So you either need to import names directly, like so:

```
from statgen import speed, durability, acceleration, handling, braking
```

Or you need to reference the variables including their namespace:

```
import statgen

print(statgen.speed())
```

etc

Namespaces allow you to use the same variable name in different files, because you can disambiguate them with the namespace. This is why the Zen of Python says that they are a honking good idea :)

So in your case you need this, to be sure:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Car_1 = Car(statgen.speed(), statgen.acceleration(), statgen.handling(), statgen.braking(), statgen.durability())
```

Comment: Wooooow I knew there was a giant wooosh somewhere. Fixed everything, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You're never calling the functions, you're just assigning the functions to the class attributes. I think it should be:

```
Car_1 = Car(speed(), acceleration(), handling(), braking(), durability())
```

Comment: I've tried this too, still returns the same "variable not defined" error.

Comment: Please edit the question and show the exact error message including the traceback.